# XCode compiling extremely slow inside VMWare

Tags: xcode, macos, vmware

The OSX 10.6.6 is installed inside VMware on Windows 7 host. The overall performance is great, However, the compiling time increased dramatically (1 hour against 2-3 min on pure MacOS). It's modern machine with Core i5 & 4GB RAM.
Here are the XBench results:
http://db.xbench.com/merge.xhtml?doc1=517768&doc2=1&setCookie=true
I think the problem could be in extremely slow 4k write value, but I don't know how to improve this.

Is there any way to increase performance?

UPD1: swap is not used, there is enough memory for all operations
the disk speed is also not related, since my another Macbook shows event worse results, and compiles hundreds times faster.

UPD2: problem solved, see my answer below

Comment: Check the swap on the guest (`free(1)` or `top(1)` should do the job) -- if you're going into swap, you might want to increase the memory granted to the guest by VMWare. Another option to help those slow read/writes would be to put the image on an SSD drive. (See [this image](http://images.anandtech.com/graphs/graph4253/36347.png) in the middle of [this review](http://www.anandtech.com/print/4253) for an idea how to improve small read/write performance. :)

Comment: swap is 0 bytes, the VM has 2gb of ram

Comment: are there any configuration options in VMWare to enable or disable disk rollback functionality? I can imagine that one or the other might be much faster than the other one. (I can convince myself there are good reasons for either one to be fastest!) Maybe also get a new drive and use a raw partition for the storage, rather than a filesystem image file.

Answer (score 7):

Sharing experience and solution.

My Xcode was running fine but when I build a project (even an empty one), it would take up to 10 minutes.

**SOLUTION:**
`Go to Xcode -> Preference -> Source Control: Dissable Source Control`

Now projects build and run in a matter of seconds.

Answer (score 4):

In VMWare, you should have a setting where you can dedicate one or two cores entirely to the virtual machine. Assuming you have quad core, maybe give MacOSX 2 or 3 cores? If you have dual-core and you've allocated 1 core to the VM (and the problem still persists), i can't say much then!

Answer (score 4):

It's good that your problem is solved, but I want to share my experience for improving vmware performance. Please do install VMware tools for mac os and they are present in .iso file.

Steps to install VMware tools for MAC OS:

1) Power on your VM.
2) At the right bottom they are some pop-up symbols(These are usually not present in full screen mode). Rightclick the CD/DVD symbol.
3) Click setting. In this window make sure that darwin.iso is selected.
4) Close this window and again right click CD/DVD symbol.
5) Click connect. An icon will appear with name darwin(300).
6) Inside this file tools are present. Install them!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was: VERY SLOW recursive searching of include paths. If non-recursive, everything works smooth.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same problem, But i want share my personal experience here.

1. My CPUs RAM capacity is 4 GB, So i allocated 3.5 GB to the VMWare
   because of this it was very slow the entire operating system.
2. So one day i clearly observed the VMWare settings, finally found the
   solution. If we allocate the RAM memory more than recommended then
   also your operating system hangs. For my System the recommended RAM
   memory is 2048MB, after adjusting this now OS is fast.
3. We can adjust the RAM memory in Devices option, inside Hardware. For
   clarification here i am attaching the screen shot.
   [image]

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it as follow:

1. Most boost I got with changing my vmware config file to disable memory 
   stored in .vmem file. In my .vmx file I added :

> ```
>   mainMem.useNamedFile = "FALSE"
>
>   prefvmx.minVmMemPct = "100"
> ```

2. Setting max cores to the guest
3. When programming with swift and XCode. Remove all comments /* */ not really used.