# Compiler Hangs In Xcode 4 on VMWare

Tags: xcode, performance, compilation, vmware

I have Mac OS X 10.6.8 installed in VMWare Workstation on my Windows 7 computer.

I downloaded Xcode 4 and after installing it, I am trying to compile an app that I created some time ago in Xcode 3.2.6.

It seems as though the second time that I try compiling since Xcode was opened, the compiler hangs. If I open Xcode and then compile, it compiles fine (maybe a bit slower than normal) but the second time I try compiling, it hangs.

When I look at the compiling log (IDK what it's officially called), I can see that it hangs during the line "Precompile (app name)_Prefix.pch".

I cannot stop the compile and I am forced to force quit Xcode.

I have come across a similar question to this: [XCode compiling extremely slow inside VMWare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522577/xcode-compiling-extremely-slow-inside-vmware)

The person who asked the question replied to his question with response:

> The problem was: VERY SLOW recursive searching of include paths. If
>   non-recursive, everything works smooth.

Since I am fairly new to Xcode and objective-c I don't really understand this answer and what I can do to fix my problem.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I updated from Xcode 4 to Xcode 4.0.2 and compiling seems to not hang now and it does compile but it sits on "Precompile (app name)_Prefix.pch" for 1-2 minutes... A lot slower than what I remember 3.2.6 being... And my iPhone simulator always starts upside down? :S

EDIT2: Hmm, everything seems to be fine now actually. Compiling got faster as I compiled more and I accidentally had the upside down orientation selected as the only supported orientation. It seems the update to 4.0.2 (or maybe just a re-install) fixed the problems because yesterday on Xcode 4 it was a nightmare.

Comment: Allow your virtual machine to access more resources (more CPU Cores and RAM). Does that help?

Comment: Check the answer which i gave here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522577/xcode-compiling-extremely-slow-inside-vmware/26795956#26795956 , it may solve your problem.